# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type "string" and "method group"

Tags: c#, string

I am checking to see if a Directory exists with this code:

```
while (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory + year.ToString))
{
  // do stuff
  year++;
}
```

year is a normal integer, currentDirectory a string. Unfortunately this Operation gives me the 
"Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type "string" and "method group"
 error mesage. I don't really want to create a new string on each Iteration when I only need to increment.

Comment: If you got a message like *Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type “string”* you may have a `+` too many in your concatenation code. Probably one `+` at the and of a line and one `+` at the beginning of the next. (as your heading ranks for that case and some may wonder)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`ToString` is a method. You need to invoke it; so you're missing `()` after `ToString`.

Change it to

```
while (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory + year.ToString()))
{
    // do stuff
    year++;
}
```

And it should work :)

Answer (score 3):

You've missed the method call on `ToString`

```
while (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory + year.ToString))
```

Should read

```
while (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory + year.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing brackets `()` after `ToString`. You need to change it to the following:

```
while (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory + year.ToString()))
{
  // do stuff
  year++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `year.ToString()`

```
while (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory + year.ToString))
```

It should be

```
while (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory + year.ToString()))
{
  // do stuff
  year++;
}
```