# Error Message: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

Tags: c#, operators

When working on a class Project in Microsoft Visual Studio, I ran across the following error:
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

These are the relevant pieces of code:

```
 public double CalculateTotalFuelCost()
    {
        double CalculateTotalFuelCost = gallonsConsumed * fuelCostPerGallon;
        return CalculateTotalFuelCost;
    }
```

and

```
   public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Destination: " + destination + "\nTotal Miles: " + distanceTraveled + "\nFuel Consumed: " + gallonsConsumed + " gallons" + "\nFuel Cost Per Gallon: $" + 
             fuelCostPerGallon + "\nTotal Fuel Cost for this Trip: $" + 
CalculateTotalFuelCost + "\nMPG: " + CalculateMilesPerGallon + 
             "\n Fuel Cost Per Mile: $" + CalculateCostPerMile;
    }
```

The error covers this small snippet of the above code.

```
+ "\nTotal Fuel Cost for this Trip: $" + CalculateTotalFuelCost
```

Everything else shows no errors.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Thank you for any help and advice that can be offered.

Comment: whens you see `method group`, think 'missing parenthesis'

Comment: This ain't VB, son!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type "string" and "method group"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066962/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-and-method-group)

Comment: Gotcha, @Jonesopolis. As CNuts put below, I see where I made my mistakes. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function you forgot the `()`

```
CalculateTotalFuelCost()
```

Do the same for all the other functions you're trying to call.

Comment: @KyleW You're welcome :) Don't forget to [Accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solved your problem.